# Java counting change error after recording user input

Tags: java

I recently asked a question about my code, and after updating it with the correct formula I was hoping I could get some insight on what I can do to get rid of this error. I will attach the code and the error at the bottom.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//The purpose of this program is to take the users input,
//And then count the change and turn it into a dollar
//Amount that is easy to read to the user

public class CountChangeWithScanner {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int quarters; //number of quarters that the user inputs
        int dimes; //number of dimes that the user inputs
        int nickels; //number of nickels that the user inputs
        int pennies; //number of pennies that the user inputs

        Scanner stdio = new Scanner(System.in); // record user input 

        double dollars; // total value of coins

        /* Prompt user to enter the number of each type of coin */

        /*Prompt user to enter the number of quarters  */

        System.out.print("Enter the number of quarters:  ");
        quarters = stdio.nextInt();
        stdio.nextLine();

        /*Prompt user to enter the number of dimes */
        System.out.print("Enter the number of dimes:  ");
        dimes = stdio.nextInt();
        stdio.nextLine();

        /*Prompt user to enter the number of nickels */
        System.out.print("Enter the number of nickels:  ");
        nickels = stdio.nextInt();
        stdio.nextLine();

        /*Prompt user to enter the number of pennies */
        System.out.print("Enter the number of pennies:  ");
        pennies = stdio.nextInt();
        stdio.nextLine();

        dollars = quarters * 25 + dimes * 10 + nickels * 5 + pennies / 100;

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("The total in dollars is $");
        System.out.println(dollars);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        at CountChangeWithScanner.main(Change counter.java:14)
```

What I'm trying to do is ask the user input, put it to the variable, and then go on to the next question. After all the questions are asked, I want the program to add them up into dollars by multiplication, and then print into dollars.

Comment: Your code runs fine: https://ideone.com/esCK7w without any compilation error.

Also, try saving the file with the class name since it's public.

Is there some more information in the exception stack trace?

Comment: after copying the exact code you sent into the same thing, i got this error. https://ideone.com/LkMIMo Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You did not provide any input.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is another dumb question, but after putting input this is what is showed. https://ideone.com/WnLEdR

Comment: Is there a newline after the 4? @JoshD'Astoli

Comment: Yes, If you do not want that remove the `stdio.nextLine();` after last input.

Answer (score 0):

> Unresolved compilation problem: at CountChangeWithScanner.main(Change counter.java:14)

You are getting *Unresolved compilation problem* because your code is not compiling. You can't run code that does not compile.

It appears that the name of the file (containing the code for class `CountChangeWithScanner`) is **`Change counter.java`**

A java source code file must contain a single, public class and the name of the file **must** be the same as the public class definition that it contains.

Hence you need to rename the file [from *Change counter.java*] to **`CountChangeWithScanner.java`**